# how to save a formula array in a cell to a vba variable

Tags: vba, save, global-variables, public, array-formulas

How can I do the following:

```
For j = 1 To MaxCol + 1
    'Select the cell on which you want to save the formula

    Cells(7, j).Select

    my_story_tab_array(j) = ActiveCell.FormulaArray
Next
```

Some of the cells in the Active Worksheet are NOT formula Arrays... some are...

I want to save them to an array() in my code (Public / Global variable) so that I can restore them later ...

TIA.

Comment: BTW - I'm only saving the 7th row of the worksheet since all formulae for every column will be identical throughout the worksheet

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you : )

```
    Sub editedmacro()
    Dim my_story_tab_array() As Variant 'Array where the formula will be store
    MaxCol = 2
    For j = 1 To MaxCol + 1
        ReDim my_story_tab_array(MaxCol + 1) 'set size of the array
        Cells(7, j).Select 'Select the cell on which you want to save the formula

        my_story_tab_array(j) = ActiveCell.FormulaArray 'store the current cell value into array
        MsgBox (my_story_tab_array(j))
    Next
   End Sub
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks - I've tried that already -- when you look at the dump of the array in memory  --- any array formula in the originating cells on the worksheet Cell(7,j) that we are attempting to copy - are stored as regular formulas?? In other words, when I go to copy the formula back into it's originating cell ... the { ... } are missing

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for sth. like this:

```
Sub example()
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(7, 3), Cells(7, 4))
    .Formula = "=SUM($A$2, $A$3) * 9"
    .FormulaArray = .FormulaR1C1
End With
End Sub
```

Regards